# Combining multiple cmake library targets into a single target failing when running under a GitHub action

Tags: github, cmake

I'm trying to set ups continuous integration workflow GitHub using a modern cmake build system. In this build system, I have two external libraries I need to find, a C and Fortran version. Since these libraries don't a build in FindLIBRARY, I had to create my own. I also wanted to set it up so that both libraries can be linked as a single target.

```
find_path (LIBRARY_INCLUDE_DIR
           NAMES library.h)
mark_as_advanced (LIBRARY_INCLUDE_DIR)

find_library(LIBRARY_C_LIBRARY
             NAMES c_version)
mark_as_advanced (LIBRARY_C_LIBRARY)
find_library(LIBRARY_Fortran_LIBRARY
             NAMES fortran_version)
mark_as_advanced (LIBRARY_Fortran_LIBRARY)

include (FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args (LIBRARY
                                   REQUIRED_VARS LIBRARY_C_LIBRARY LIBRARY_Fortran_LIBRARY     LIBRARY_INCLUDE_DIR

if (LIBRARY_FOUND)
    set (LIBRARY_INCLUDE_DIRS ${LIBRARY_INCLUDE_DIR})
    set (LIBRARY_LIBRARIES "${LIBRARY_C_LIBRARY} ${LIBRARY_Fortran_LIBRARY}")

    if (NOT TARGET LIBRARY::LIBRARY_C)
        add_library (LIBRARY::LIBRARY_C UNKNOWN IMPORTED)
        set_target_properties (LIBRARY::LIBRARY_C PROPERTIES
                               IMPORTED_LOCATION ${LIBRARY_C_LIBRARY}
                               INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${LIBRARY_INCLUDE_DIR})
    endif ()
    if (NOT TARGET LIBRARY::LIBRARY_Fortran)
        add_library (LIBRARY::LIBRARY_Fortran UNKNOWN IMPORTED)
        set_target_properties (LIBRARY::LIBRARY_Fortran PROPERTIES
                               IMPORTED_LOCATION ${LIBRARY_Fortran_LIBRARY}
                               INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${LIBRARY_INCLUDE_DIR})
    endif ()

    if (NOT TARGET LIBRARY::LIBRARY)
        add_library (LIBRARY::LIBRARY INTERFACE IMPORTED)
        target_link_libraries (LIBRARY::LIBRARY INTERFACE LIBRARY::LIBRARY_C LIBRARY::LIBRARY_Fortran)
    endif ()
endif ()
```

Then when I go to import and link this in my own target

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.14)

project (my_project C Fortran)

set (CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH};${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)
find_package (LIBRARY MODULE REQUIRED)

add_library(my_library STATIC)

... # Add target sources here.

if (LIBRARY_FOUND)
    target_link_libraries (my_library INTERFACE LIBRARY::LIBRARY)
endif ()
```

Then I use `my_library` in an executable somewhere.

```
add_executable (my_program)
target_link_libraries (my_program my_library)
```

Everything works fine when I run it on my local dev machine (MacOS 10.14.6). `my_program` picks up all the compile definitions, include directories and compiler flag properties that are set on the linked targets. However it's failing when I try to run it as a GitHub action (ubuntu-latest). When I build with `make VERBOSE=1`, I can see that the `LIBRARY_INCLUDE_DIR` property is missing. Both machines are running the same version of cmake.

Comment: " I can see that the LIBRARY_INCLUDE_DIR property is missing." - So it is the **first line** in your script which has been failed. How this problem is related with "combing CMake library targets" as written in the title?

Comment: `find_path` defines the `LIBRARY_INCLUDE_DIR` variable.

Comment: Yes, the first line, `find_path`, defines `LIBRARY_INCLUDE_DIR` variable. If the header file is not found, then variable is set to `-NOTFOUND`. By "I can see that the `LIBRARY_INCLUDE_DIR` property is missing." you mean the latest case, don't you?

Comment: It finding the header just fine.

Comment: Oh, then I incorrectly understood your problem statement - "I can see that the LIBRARY_INCLUDE_DIR property is missing.". Could you elaborate it? Does it mean that value of `LIBRARY_INCLUDE_DIR` isn't passed to the compiler? If so, have you tried (for debug purposes) whether linking with separate targets works: `target_link_libraries (my_library INTERFACE LIBRARY::LIBRARY_C LIBRARY::LIBRARY_FORTRAN)`?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the fix was to change

```
if (LIBRARY_FOUND)
    target_link_libraries (my_library INTERFACE LIBRARY::LIBRARY)
endif ()
```

to

```
if (LIBRARY_FOUND)
    target_link_libraries (my_library PUBLIC LIBRARY::LIBRARY)
endif ()
```

Linking it as an `INTERFACE`, meant that things that would link to `my_library` would see the include directory but the `my_library` sources did not.